# UITabBarItemに設定した画像が塗りつぶされてしまう

Tags: objective-c, pdf

Xcodeで、pdfをVectorでimagesetに登録しています。
そのリソースをタブバーの画像として使用しているのですが、
presentViewControllerで画面を表示し、
画面を閉じると画像の白い部分が塗りつぶされてしまいます。
アクティブタブの場合は、完全に画面が切り替わると、
正常に戻りますが、アクティブタブで無い場合、
塗りつぶされたままになってしまいます。
塗りつぶされた状態にならない方法はありますか？

iOS8で発生しており、iOS6では発生しません。

Comment: 「画像の白い部分が塗りつぶされてしまいます」という状況が少し不明確なので、画像のキャプチャを貼り付けておくと、回答者の助けになると思います。あと、「pdfをVectorでimagesetに登録しています」とありますが、実際のコードも可能であれば載せておくと良いと思います。

Comment: タイトルのクラス名（UITabBarItem）を修正しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。イメージを登録できれば良いのですが、今回は無理そうです...

Comment: - (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode;
で、UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginalを指定して作成した画像をUITabBarItemに設定することで解決できました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合には、回答を自分で書いてベストアンサーにしておくと、他の方の参考になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

今更ですが...
- (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode; で、UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginalを指定して作成した画像をUITabBarItemに設定することで解決できました。

```
@interface UIImage (ForTabBar)
+ (UIImage*)imageNamedForTabBar:(NSString*)name;
@end

@implementation UIImage (ForTabBar)
+ (UIImage*)imageNamedForTabBar:(NSString*)name {
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    if ([image respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
        return [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    }
    return image;
}
@end


    // タブバーに画像を設定
    if ([controller.tabBarItem respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:)]) {
        // iOS7から、普通にimageNamedで読み込んだ画像を設定すると
        // UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplateモードで描画されるそうです。
        // オリジナル画像を表示する場合は、UIImageのimageWithRenderingMode関数で読み込んだ画像を
        // 設定しないと塗りつぶされます。
        controller.tabBarItem = [[HDMainTabBarItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:title
                                 image:[UIImage imageNamedForTabBar:@"select.png"]
                                 selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamedForTabBar:@"unselect.png"]];
    } else {
        UIImage* unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamedForTabBar:@"unselect.png"];
        controller.tabBarItem = [[HDMainTabBarItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:title
                                 image:unselectedImage
                                 tag:0];
        [controller.tabBarItem
         setFinishedSelectedImage:unselectedImage
         withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamedForTabBar:@"select.png"]];
    }
```